# Using Zizaco Entrust error in hasRole() - Laravel 4.1

Tags: laravel-4

I'm working in a sample project using Zizaco Entrust.

All insalled via composer and following the instructions [here](http://splashurl.com/lsxgzj6).

The issue is I obtain the following error in my route.php:

> Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
>   Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\GenericUser::hasRole()

I'm using Easy PHP with PHP 5.4.14 version and my User model is:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;
use Zizaco\Entrust\HasRole;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {
    use HasRole;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password');

    /**
     * Get the unique identifier for the user.
     *
     * @return mixed
     */


    public function getAuthIdentifier()
    {
        return $this->getKey();
    }

    /**
     * Get the password for the user.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAuthPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * Get the e-mail address where password reminders are sent.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getReminderEmail()
    {
        return $this->email;
    }

}
```

Thanks for help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use same table and class name. As follows.

```
class User extends....
protected $table = 'user';
...
```